# To which EG (Entgeltgruppe) does a master's graduate belong to in Germany?

Tags: germany, salary

I am a Master's student, soon I will be finishing my master's thesis. I am looking for a full-time job and would like to know the exact Entgeltgruppe I belong to. I am studying in Baden-Württemberg, Germany.

Comment: What kind of position are you looking for? PhD student at a university? What field are we talking about? Are you looking for a job starting after finishing your Master's thesis? Please provide some more details.

Comment: I would recommend to read some job adverts that fit your qualification, and you will quickly find out the typical *Entgeltgruppe*.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
I am looking for a job starting after finishing my Master's thesis, in the e-mobility domain as a Developer.

Comment: Hmm, can you specify if you are looking for a job in the public or in the private sector? It would be good if you edited the info into the question.

Comment: I'm under the impression that the question is based on a misunderstanding. You say you'd like to work as a developer in e-mobility. This sounds like a job in the industry, so I presume that the notion "Entgeltgruppe" in this context refers to the IG Metall collective wage agreement? (As opposed to the TV-L agreement for public servants which the answers here seem to assume, probably based on your question being asked on Academia StackExchange.) If this is the case, please be advised that: (i) not all companies in the e-mobility business are subject to the IG Metall collective wage agreement;

Comment: (ii) the details of IG metall collective wage agreement depend strongly on the federal state where you are going to work; (iii) in some (many?) collective wage agreements, your "Entgeltgruppe" will not depend on your qualification but on the qualification required for your position (which might be lower than your actual qualification), so the answer to your question depends on the precise position you're applying to (I'm not sure, though, how precisely the IG Metall agreement handles this point);

Comment: (iv) depending on the company, the general situation on the job market, and some more specific individual factors, it is sometimes possible that you will be paid more than required by a collective wage agreement (but this really depends, so please don't make any assumptions); (v) in any case, questions on salaries in the private sector don't seem to be on topic on Academia StackExchange (which is why I put this in a comment rather than an answer).

Comment: I think this question is absolutely in need of more details, because without any further information, it doesn't make any sense. The term "Entgeltgruppe" is meaningless without looking at a specific position/employer. Once you have finished your Master's degree and start looking for a job (*any* job), your salary is largely open and totally depends on what kind of job you get and what salary you agree upon with the future employer.

Answer (score -2):

Depends on the Bundesland, company/institute, and your contract negotiations. Often the relevant factor is *not* the EG but the percentage of the employment time. For example, E13 with 75% is more than E14 with 50% and so on. However, for a full time job it is often 100%, unless you are a PhD student or anywhere else in Academia after the Masters.

Also depends on the sector you are working in. Natural sciences seem to pay more than social sciences. Often the negotiations in the private sector are the *last* step in the process.

PhD students belong to E13 with roughly 50-75%. So that should answer close to your question. In the private sector I personally know people who on average get about 100% TVöD 13.

Comment: I have difficulties to understand the second paragraph: The first and the third paragraph seem to refer to the TV-L collective wage agreement, but in your second paragraph you talk about the private sector. Could you clarify?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. If one wants to go to private sector, it can be difficult to tell what to negotiate, so the corresponding TVöD can be used as a reference point.

Answer (score -3):

> Entgeltgruppe 9b TVöD gilt typischerweise für Beschäftigte mit
> absolviertem Hochschulstudium und Bachelor, vergleichbar mit dem
> gehobenen Dienst bei Beamten.

3.044,70 €  ohne Berufserfahrung

https://www.jobs-beim-staat.de/tarif/tvoed-bund_e9b

That's the monthly wage for jobs in the public sector (before taxes, which are around ~40% of the salary).
As a PhD, you should get TV-L E13, but almpost never a full position, it can be anywehre from 50% to 100% (paid, you are obviously expected to work 100% of the time, because you have the privilege of working and researching in the mighty German system).

In the private sector it will be probably quite a bit less, depending on the sector and on your (language) skills.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but I think some things in this answer should be adjusted. The 40% taxes you're referring to are actually not always around 40%, but depend quite strongly on the gross salary; besides, a significant fraction of them are not actually taxes, but social insurance fees. Concerning the last paragraph: this depends heavily on various individual factors. In general, positions in STEM fields are in many cases (but not always) paid better in the industry compared to universities.

Comment: @JochenGlueck "social insurance fees", not only, there is also the health insurance! But I always found pretty formal to call them insurance, when they are compulsory and blanket covering the population. Not forgetting the absurd minijob, where you pay no taxes but in principle you still have to pay the health insurance. Reg the difference between STEM and non STEM, if you have a non-German skin and you speak German at a level lower than B2, see https://ftp.iza.org/dp12358.pdf regarding german (un)succesful integreation of non-native workers.

Comment: Yes, indeed - actually, I was mainly thinking about health insurance, but you're of course right that it's not counted as a "social" insurance. The reason why I find the distinction (between insurance fess and taxes) important is that these fees cover a lot of (expensive) things that people need to pay from their net salary in some countries (if they would like to have, say, health insurance and a pension plan). I think comparing net salaries across countries is difficult anyway, and labelling (obligatory) insurance fees as taxes makes even more difficult. [...]

Comment: [...] Regarding discrimination: For sure, I don't doubt for a second that there's a lot of discrimination happening within the German job market. Whether any particular person will experience such discrimination, and if yes to what extent, is of course impossible to predict. (Sometimes, collective wage agreements might for instance offer some degree of protection here, when the "Entgeltgruppe" is required to be associated with the specific position; but of course this protection will be far from complete, and it can only protect people from very specific types of discrimination.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck In Germany the health/social insurances are included and taken off from your salary, so my definition of "taxes". 
I understand the situation about other countries, but considering the health insurance optional is ridicolous and a bet that only young (supposed to be) healthy people can take (I am explicitly referring to the US). So it can very well be counted in the taxes for the german salary. But I agree I am imprecise in my definition, on the other hand they are very inefficient "health system and social taxes": they are even proportional to the salary and not to the risk!